# Inbound endpoint configuration, reading coordination parameter value from a file

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an inbound endpoint configuration and I want to read the value of the `coordination` parameter from a file.

I can read the `java.naming.provider.url` value from a file with this way

```
<parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" key="conf:/configurations/inbound/InboundJNPURLVal"/>
```

I tried same structure for the `coordination` parameter value,

```
<parameter name="coordination" key="conf:/configurations/inbound/InboundCoordinationVal"/>
```

Although the `InboundCoordinationVal` file content is "false", the value of the `coordination` parameter was "true" in the WSO2 management console.

[image: Inbound Endpoint conf in WSO2 management console]

Is there any way to manage this value of the `coordination` parameter?

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: This is a bug in the management console. We have created an issue [1] to fix this issue. Please note that the inbound endpoint reads the coordination from registry and use that value.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4389

Comment: Thanks for info @ShakilaSasikaran. I'm also tracking this issue.